# Cant access WCF self hosted service through IE

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a self hosted WCF service.

I think the service is hosting ok but when I try and access the URL from IE nothing happens.

I have added some debugging and it looks like the service is hosting itself no problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Ash

Code to host service with debug

```
    Type serviceType = typeof(MessageHandlerServer);
    Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, serviceUri);
    host.Open();


    #region Output dispatchers listening
    foreach (Uri uri in host.BaseAddresses)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", uri.ToString());
    }
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Number of dispatchers listening : {0}", host.ChannelDispatchers.Count);
foreach (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers)
{
      Console.WriteLine("\t{0}, {1}", dispatcher.Listener.Uri.ToString(), dispatcher.BindingName);
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate Host");
Console.ReadLine();
#endregion
```

Output is

```
Number of dispatchers listening : 2
http://localhost:8080/, http://tempuri.org/:WSDualHttpBinding
http://localhost:8080/, ServiceMetadataBehaviorHttpGetBinding

Press <ENTER> to terminate Host
```

Heres the service config, ignore the module downloader bit (unless you think thats causing the problem) its not relevant for now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
         <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
               <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                  <filter type="" />
               </add>
               <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                  <filter type="" />
               </add>
            </listeners>
         </source>
         <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                  <filter type="" />
               </add>
               <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                  <filter type="" />
               </add>
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
      <sharedListeners>
         <add initializeData="C:\Users\Ash\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FrameworkPrototype\Driver\App_messages.svclog"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
         </add>
         <add initializeData="C:\Users\Ash\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FrameworkPrototype\Driver\App_tracelog.svclog"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
         </add>
      </sharedListeners>
   </system.diagnostics>
   <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
     <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageHandlerServer" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpStreaming" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
                 transferMode="Streamed"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MessageHandlerServer" behaviorConfiguration="defaultProfile" >
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageHandlerServer" contract="IMessageHandlerServer"  />
      </service>
      <service name="ModuleDownloader"  behaviorConfiguration="defaultProfile" >
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8082" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="HttpStreaming" contract="IModuleDownloader"  />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultProfile">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="MyServerCert" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="UsernameValidator, MessageHandlerServer" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How are you getting that output if the service isn't working?  Also, please share your config, etc.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access? Also, since you declared the endpoint on config, can you post the <system.serviceModel> section as well?

Comment: A wsDualHttpBinding cannot be just "accessed" from the URL - you need a full-fledged SOAP client - i.e. a client app or WCF Test Client. Do you get your WSDL at `http://localhost:8080/?wsdl` ??

Comment: Also, why are you using wsDualHttpBinding?  Is that a requirement?

Comment: @Terry- The output is produced by the console app hosting the service. I would expect that the bit of code producing this output would error if the service was not hosted correctly. As for the DualHTTPBinding, yes its a requirement. I need duplex communication with the client. I'll add my config.

Comment: @Carlos - I was trying to access http://localhost:8080 ... I'll add my config.

Comment: @Marc - I do have a fully fledged SOAP client but I made some changes to the service and now one way calls to the service throw no errors(that I can see) but never reach the service ( ie no break points are hit ) my first debug check was to see if the service was running, ie can I access it through IE. I cannot access http://localhost:8080/?wsdl

Comment: I think you need to define Metadata Exchange Endpoint

Answer (score 2):

well unless you are getting IE to browse to the *MEX*, IE may not actually show much.

one of the easiest ways to test a WCF service is by way of MS's **WCF Test Client** (**WcfTestClient.exe**). I would try this before say using IE.  This will not only test whether:

- your service is *contactable*
- your service is *usable* via standard WCF protocols (such as XML SOAP)
- your service is *NOT using any datatypes that do not adhere to SOAP*

It also provides a nice little error dialog if something goes wrong, complete with details.

I notice your service is referring to *X509*. Is that setup correctly? Maybe try without?  Sometimes it best to turn off security until you know for sure your service is contactable and invokable.  If that works well maybe then turn on security.

An alternative to self-hosting is to *host .svc WCF services in IIS*.  This takes alot of the guess work out.  IIS's **Manager** GUI allows you to easily "browse" the .**svc** from the web applications **Content** folder, the output showing up rather nicely in IE (assuming your service is pushing out **MEX**)